# How to increase clickable area surrounding a Vuetify v-slider's nob?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, user-experience

How do you increase the clickable area surrounding the nobs of Vuetify's [`v-slider`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/sliders/) component?

[image]

I would like to do this in order to make it easier for users to 'grab the nob' and control the slider, particularly for the sake of mobile UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method to increase the clickable area of the draggable `v-slider` and `v-range-slider` nobs using CSS. It should be noted that, as of February 2021, [`v-slider`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-slider/) and [`v-range-slider`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-range-slider/) do not yet have built-in props to control this functionality.

My answer is based on [this github comment](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4356#issuecomment-727628661) (note: it is worth reading this entire github issue thread, as it concerns the OP's question).

```scss
<style scoped lang="scss">
  .my-slider-class >>> .v-slider__thumb:after { 
    transition: 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.5, 1); 
    content: ''; 
    color: inherit; 
    width: 400%; 
    height: 400%; 
    border-radius: 50%; 
    background: transparent; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: -150%; 
    top: -150%; 
  }
  .my-slider-class >>> .v-slider__thumb:before { 
    transition: 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.5, 1); 
    content: ''; 
    color: inherit; 
    width: 200%; 
    height: 200%; 
    border-radius: 50%; 
    background: currentColor; 
    opacity: 0.3; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: -50%; 
    top: -50%; 
    transform: scale(0.1); 
    pointer-events: none; 
  }
</style>
```